# CSS and Defintion Lists - Selecting specifc Definition Descriptions

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible, via CSS alone, to choose the following from this HTML block?  Or choose everything but what I want to select?

```
<dl>
<dt>dt one</dt>
<dd>dd one A</dt>
<dt>dt two</dt>
<dd>choose this dd and only this dd</dd>
<dd>dd two B</dd>
<dt>dt three</dt>
<dd>dd three A</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like either `dd:nth-child(4)` or `dd:nth-of-type(2)` will get you that element, unless there are conditions you haven't mentioned in your question *at all* (it's deceptively simple in its current form).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. W3Schools has an excellent resource: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

You might find the n-th child selectors of particular interest.

Comment: I should qualify this.  In a dynamic environment, I want to choose the DD anytime it has an adjacent sibling.  So, yes, in this instance, I could use n-th child selectors, but not if this changes.

Comment: Looking at the W3Schools link, it appears that you could use `dd~dd`, which should select every DD that is preceded by another DD.